# How can I add space between editable text and prefix icon in textField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and am learning about textfields. I have a textfield that looks like this:

[image]

I want to add some padding between the prefix icon and the editable text. Here's my code:

```
TextField(
  style: const TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromARGB(125, 0, 0, 0),
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
    hintText: 'Full Name',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[300]),
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    filled: true,
    prefixIcon: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          right: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey[300]!,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.person_outline,
        color: kPurple,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  cursorColor: kPurple,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Wrap the Icon Widget With the Padding. or alternatively add padding to the container,

-- try The Code Below Working Fine on my Side

```
   TextField(
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Color.fromARGB(125, 0, 0, 0),
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
            hintText: 'Full Name',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[300]),
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            filled: true,
            prefixIcon: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: 40, top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  right: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey[300]!,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.person_outline,
                color: Colors.purpleAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          cursorColor: Colors.purple,
        ),
```

Comment: Does not work. Makes the icon askew. Please show some code with your answer that could be the solution to the question. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I  have updated the answer   with  code

Comment: That did not add space between the icon (container) and the editable text. It just added padding to the icon. I need to add space between the 'divider line' and 'Full name'

Comment: then replace padding with margin, updated code

Answer (score -4):

To add space between the editable text and the prefix icon in a TextFormField in Flutter, you can make use of the prefixIcon property along with a Padding widget. You can wrap the prefixIcon with a Padding widget to control the spacing.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    hintText: 'Enter',
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 12,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
      color: AppColors.danger,
    ),
    prefixIcon: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 14), // Adjust the spacing as needed
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            right: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Icon(Icons.numbers_rounded),
      ),
    ),
    prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: 62,
      minHeight: 48,
    ),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(14),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  ),
),
```

In this code, the Padding widget is used to add space to the right of the prefixIcon. You can adjust the EdgeInsets.only(right: 14) value according to your preferred spacing. Feel free to experiment with different values until you achieve the desired layout.

This should help you achieve the spacing between the editable text and the prefix icon in the TextFormField. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!

Comment: I am a bit curious how you could miss the banner that provides this information *while you are answering*?  Any chance you'd explain that?  It might help us understand why users continue to post AI even after we thought they had clear warning.  Thanks!